# Limiting model validation to only records associated with the current_user in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, validation, rails-activerecord

I have an Invitations system that allows users to nominate others to join a beta.  I need to validate the email address the user is sending the invitation to and ensure that the email address is unique, but only within the scope of the `current_user`'s list of invitations.

In other words, the model should allow for the same email address to exist within the invitation system, but not allow duplicates within the scope of the `current_user`'s list of invites.

My `UserModel` has:

```
has_many :invitations

validates_uniqueness_of :email
```

and my `InvitationModel` has:

```
belongs_to :user
```

I can't put `validates_uniqueness_of :email` inside the `InvitationModel` since I need to allow multiple instances of a given email address within the database, but ensure that each instance has a unique sender (User).

Any ideas on how to limit the validation to the scope of the `current_user`?

Comment: `validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :user(_id)`

Comment: The above was throwing an error, but a bit of fiddling gave me:

    `validates_uniqueness_of :email, :scope => :user`

I still have to test, but I'll plus one you for setting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need a scope on your validation. This will allow the same email address to be used multiple times, but only once per user.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :user_id
```

Also, since email addresses are case-insensitive, I recommend adding insensitivity to the scope.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :email, scope: :user_id, case_sensitive: false
```

Cite: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validates_uniqueness_of